# what's the difference between appending a child element and setting innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

In the first example, the script was executed, but not in the second example, the Dom results are the same.

```
// executable
var c = 'alert("append a div in which there is a script element")';
var div = document.createElement('div');
var script_2 = document.createElement('script');
script_2.textContent = c;
div.appendChild(script_2);
document.body.appendChild(div);

// unexecutable although the dom result is same as above case
var d = '<script>alert("append a div that has script tag as innerHTML")';
var div_d = document.createElement('div');
div_d.innerHTML = d;
document.body.appendChild(div_d);
```

Comment: i think you have not closed the script tag properly in second part !
var d = '<script>alert("append a div that has script tag as innerHTML")';

Comment: oh.sorry for missing closing tag in the second part,the script in the second part was still not executed after adding closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.innerHTML` allows you to add as much HTML as you want in one easy call.

`.appendChild` allows you to add a single element (Or multiple elements if you append a DocumentFragment).

If you use `.innerHTML` then you need to include the opening and closing tags correctly. Your HTML must be proper.

When elements that were created using `document.createElement` then auto generate the appropriate opening and closing tags.

Your example for `.innerHTML` is not properly formed. Instead of:

```
var d = '<script>alert("append a div that has script tag as innerHTML")';
```

it should be:

```
var d = '<script>alert("append a div that has script tag as innerHTML")</script>';
```

**UPDATE:**

Interesting!!

I know that, in the past, your second example would have worked. But it seems that, probably for security reasons, the browser no longer allows you to insert `<script>` through `.innerHTML`.

I tried on Chrome 62 and it fails. Firefox 57 fails and Safari 11.0.2 fails.

My best guess is that this is a security update.

Look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

And go down to the **Security considerations** section.

**It reads:**

It is not uncommon to see innerHTML used to insert text in a web page. This comes with a security risk.

```
const name = "John";
// assuming 'el' is an HTML DOM element
el.innerHTML = name; // harmless in this case

// ...

name = "<script>alert('I am John in an annoying alert!')</script>";
el.innerHTML = name; // harmless in this case
```

Although this may look like a cross-site scripting attack, the result is harmless. **HTML5 specifies that a  tag inserted via innerHTML should not execute.**

Comment: the script in the second part was still not executed  after adding closing tag